# Poner Focus a la primer columna de la tabla de un DataGridView

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo una Ventana de búsqueda donde coloco el nombre de cliente en textBox, al dar enter busca en la base de datos y devuelve la información a mi tabla.  quiero que cuando de Enter en la caja de texto  y la tabla me devolvió una lista de resultados, el Focus se pase ala primer columna de la tabla. Lo en intentado la función '''tablaCuenta.Select();''' pero solo me sirve cuando la tabla me devuelve un solo resultado. cuando devuelve mas de dos, el Focus siempre se pasa ala segunda fila de la tabla. y al dar Enter en alguna fila me debe de dar los datos de la fila seleccionada, pero me devuelve los datos de la siguiente fila seleccionada.

Este es el código: si la tabla Cuenta no esta Vacia, quiero que el puntero  o Focus me lo posicione en la primera Fila de la tabla. en Intentado Con Fucus(),Select() y Active Control, pero al dar enter siempre me los datos de la siguiente fila a la seleccionada.

```
           if (tablaCuenta.Rows.Count>0)
                    {

                        var row = tablaCuenta.CurrentRow;
                        if (row != null)
                        {
                            row.Selected = true;
                            tablaCuenta.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
                            tablaCuenta.CurrentCell = tablaCuenta.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
                            this.ActiveControl = tablaCuenta;
                            this.tablaCuenta.Focus();
                            this.tablaCuenta.Select();
                            MessageBox.Show("" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo que tienes

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes intentar con esto?

```
tablaCuenta.ClearSelection();
int nRowIndex = tablaCuenta.Rows.Count - 1;

tablaCuenta.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;
tablaCuenta.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: No funciono. Sale lo mismo me arroja los datos de la siguiente fila a la Seleccionada.

Answer (score 0):

El problemas era el Mismo Enter, ya que al dar Enter sobre una fila de un DataGridView, este esta fijado para movernos a hacia abajo en la tabla. es por eso que al dar Enter siempre me daba los Datos de la siguiente fila. para Evitar eso solo agregue el siguiente código que evita eso mismo.

```
 private void TablaBuscar_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            EnviarCuenta();
        }
    }
```